# why package titlesec causes tex4ht to give error when using $[]$ in section title?

Tags: titlesec, tex4ht

texlive 2014, Linux

This MWE fails when using `$[B]$` in section title when the package `titlesec` is loaded

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\section{this is my $[B]$ section}
test
\end{document}
```

Error is

```
htlatex foo.tex

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht))
(./foo.aux)
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> }

l.4 \section{this is my $[B]$ section}                                          
?
```

When commenting the `titlesec` package, it compiles OK. Also, If I load the package, but change the title to `$(B)$` instead of `$[B]$` then it compiles OK as well. Only when using `[]` it is not happy.

The above MWE compiles OK with pdflatex and latex.

Why does it fail in tex4ht?

```
 Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `titlesec.4ht` macro `\ttl@straight@i` is redefined

```
\let\ttl:straight@i\ttl@straight@i
\def\ttl@straight@i#1[#2]#3{%
```

original `\ttl@straight@i` is saved ad `\ttl:straight@i` and `\ttl@straight@i` is redefined to do some additional things. as you can see, `[]` characters are used as delimiters. Saved original `\ttl@straight@i` is then called with

```
 \ttl:straight@i{#1}[#2]{#3}%
```

and it seems this is the place where it goes wrong. I tried to fix it with adding brackets around the argument:

```
 \ttl:straight@i{#1}[{#2}]{#3}%
```

and it seems to compile without error, but I am not sure whether this doesn't break something else, so I can't confirm that this fix is safe.

**Original answer:**

It seems that some macro in `tex4ht` configuration for `titlesec` is using `]` as delimiter, so you must protect it if that character appears in your section title. Simplest thing you can do is it to use `{}` around your math:

```
\section{this is my {$[B]$} section}
```