# problem with titlesec package with tex4ht when using starred version of \section

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, tex4ht

I just updated my texlive 2014 using tlmgr to fix an [older related problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185866/why-package-titlesec-causes-tex4ht-to-give-error-when-using-in-section-titl) with using titlesec with tex4ht.

But it seems a new problem now shows up. This show up only when using the starred version of the section.  Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\section*{$ \left(  a  \right) $}
\end{document}
```

htlatex foo.tex

```
(./foo2.aux)
! Argument of \im:g has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 \section*{$ \left(  a  \right) $}
```

The problem goes away when changing `\section*` to `\section` or when removing the `titlesec` package.

It seems the use of `\left(` and `\right)` is confusing tex4ht support for titlesec, since this works compiles with no error:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}

\section*{$ (a) $}

\end{document}
```

Here is '\listfiles'

```
>pdflatex foo2.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) 

*File List*
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
titlesec.sty    2011/12/15 v2.10.0 Sectioning titles
```

Comment: this behavior shows with my patch for `titlesec` and image math, with `mathml` output everything is fine. the problem also shows only when section title contains only math. if text is contained, it compiles correctly. do you really use section titles containing only math?

Comment: possible workaround is to use titlesec only with pdflatex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

potential bug reports in systems should probably be raised with the maintainers rather than here but anyway you can do the following workaround.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand\zz{$\left(  a  \right) $}
\begin{document}
\section*{\protect\zz}
\end{document}
```

Hard to think of any case when you'd actually want `\left\right` in a section head....